# Show that $\frac{\|\mathbf{u}\, +\,\mathbf{v}\|\, + \,\|\mathbf{u}\,-\,\mathbf{v}\|}{2} \leq \|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{v}\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am certain that we need to use the triangle inequality, that is

$\|\mathbf{u} +\mathbf{v}\|\leq \|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{v}\| $

However, I cannot find a way to proceed from here.

Something tells me that the proof is simple but it doesn't come to me.

Comment: What happens if you apply the triangle inequality to $||u-v||$?

Comment: $|u+v|\le|u|+|v|$ and $|u-v|\le|u|+|-v|=|u|+|v|$. Adding gives the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality,

$\|\mathbf{u} +\mathbf{v}\|\leq \|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{v}\|,\quad\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|\leq \|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{v}\|\;$ hence $\;\|\mathbf{u} +\mathbf{v}\|+\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|\leq 2(\|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{v}\|).$

Answer (score 4):

Using the triangle inequality on both absolute values on the left hand side gives you

$$\text{LHS (left hand side)} \leq  \frac{||u|| + ||v|| + ||u|| + ||v||}{2} = \frac{2||u|| + 2||v||}{2} = ||u|| + ||v||_. $$

Comment: Up voted this one over the others because it doesn't unnecessarily focus on the negative sign.